# Adding, Modifying and selecting the new state from Spartacus store

Tags: ngrx-store, spartacus-storefront

Since we are migrating to the Spartacus application. I am trying to use the OOTB Store available.
I have created actions, Reducers, and selectors. But I am unable to connect to the OOTB Spartacus store available.

It would be helpful if I get a way to connect to the Spartacus store and modify the state within the store.

NOTE: When I tried to create the store using StoreModule.forRoot(). It is working as expected. But it is a local store, I need to reuse the OOTB store available